# Override/Bypass Spring Boot default login page to okta OIDC login page

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, okta

I am trying to implement OIDC with Spring Boot - Okta… I was able to run the application and everything is working fine…my question here, is there any way to override the default login page of Spring Boot, where it will provide the link of okta/any OIDC provider which will take to the okta/corresponding login page…
I need assistance on overriding/bypassing the default spring boot login page and upon hitting any of the app uri(s), it should take directly to the okta/corresponding oidc prover login page…

please let me know if you need any additional info and any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To override/bypass the default spring boot login page. We can do following by creating Spring Security Configuration:

```
 @Configuration
class OAuth2SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth_login").
permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .oauth2Login().loginPage("/oauth_login");
   }
} 

//Login controller for handling:
  @Controller
class LoginController {

  @RequestMapping("/oauth_login")
 String loginPage() {
    //redirecting to 
    return "redirect:/oauth2/authorization/okta";
  }
}
```